# C# - Prism for WPF - Common modules' libraries upgrading strategy

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, versioning

I'm designing a composite WPF/MVVM application using Prism patterns. I've read the [Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism Library 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) for WPF and I am familiar with most of the patterns described.

My application's modules will consist of a number of binaries (dll-s) and some of them will include a *shared library*, which will define *public interfaces* to MVVM models, event classes for event aggregator and services implemented by that module. Other modules would be able to reference such a library and work with its models, events and services through public interfaces and IoC.

Let's say **ModuleA.Shared** shared library includes a public interface for its *SampleModel* and *SampleService*, which performs work with *SampleModel*:

```cs
namespace ModuleA.Shared
{
    interface ISampleModel
    {
       int SampleProp01 { get; set; }
       int SampleProp02 { get; set; }
    }

    interface ISampleService
    {
       ISampleModel GetSampleModelInstance();
       void SaveSampleModelInstance(ISampleModel obj);
    }
}
```

Now say **ModuleB** (in a non-shared binary) uses **ModuleA**'s public library:

```cs
namespace ModuleB.Engine
{
    class SampleClass
    {
        void SampleMethod()
        {
            ModuleA.Shared.ISampleService srvc = SomeIoCContainer.Resolve<ModuleA.Shared.ISampleService>();
            ModuleA.Shared.ISampleModel obj = srvc.GetSampleModelInstance();

            // Do some work on obj...

            srvc.SaveSampleModelInstance(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, now let's say **ModuleB** is developed and mantained by a **third-party** (like a third-party plugin). At some point in time I add a new property to *ModuleA.Shared.ISampleModel*:

```cs
namespace ModuleA.Shared
{
    interface ISampleModel
    {
       int SampleProp01 { get; set; }
       int SampleProp02 { get; set; }
       int NewProp { get; set; } // <-- New property
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The final user upgrades my application, so the old **ModuleA**'s binaries get replaced with the new ones. **ModuleB** is distributed by a third-party and its binaries stay the same.

Since **ModuleA** and **ModuleB** are now compiled with different versions of **ModuleA.Shared.ISampleModel**, I assume IoC resolving will not succeed and the application will end in an exception.

What I am asking is what are the good practices / patterns for resolving this kind of issuses? How to make some modules upgradable without breaking the support for third-party modules which depend on them and were built with an older version of their shared libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely independent of whether you use prism or not. You're providing a plugin api (through the use of prism's module disconvery), and you have to plan for versioning your api.

First of all, once a version of the api is released, it's frozen. You cannot ever touch it (unless you want your third parties to recompile everything, making them and your customers unhappy, to say the least).

Instead of *changing* the api, release a new version of it:

```
interface ISampleModelV1
{
   int SampleProp01 { get; set; }
   int SampleProp02 { get; set; }
}
```

becomes

```
interface ISampleModelV2
{
   int SampleProp01 { get; set; }
   int SampleProp02 { get; set; }
   int NewProp { get; set; } // <-- New property
}
```

A third party can then decide to either continue to use `ISampleModelV1` or switch to `ISampleModelV2` if they need `NewProp`. Your app, of course, will have to support both of them.

As this gets ugly sooner or later as the amount of api versions increases, you might want to deprecate the old ones, e.g. if your app goes from 2.5 to 3.0, you could remove support for api 1.x... be sure to communicate these decisions to customers and third parties early enough, though.

BTW:

> Challenges Not Addressed by Prism
>   [...] Application versioning

Comment: An excellent answer, thank you very much! The solution you described would work well. Out of curiosity - are you aware of any other versioning strategies for composite app architectures?

Comment: Not really, in the end it's a question of how often you need to provide a new api and how long you have to support old api versions. That's a thing product-management has to discuss with whomever pays for the development...